# Atom doesn't replace on auto complete

Tags: css, atom-editor

I don't know if this is a bug or something wrong i am doing but when ever i type something and press enter to select from the auto complete menu it leaves whatever is written before... or specifically the @ symbol for now

here a picture demonstration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aQq9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qreQV.png)

So more to the question, Atom `does` replace whatever you type if you chose to auto-complete in contrary to what Brent said below. In an html file try typing `dv` or `btn` and select to auto-complete you'll then see that it replaces what you've typed. So this behavior is only (as far as i am concerned) replicable with symbols

Comment: Do you have any extra packages installed in atom?

Comment: @TidyDev no extra packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Autocomplete](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/autocomplete/) section of the [Atom Flight manual:](http://flight-manual.atom.io/)

> By default, the autocomplete system will look through the current open file for strings that match what you're **starting** to type.

If you've typed in part of a keyword that Atom doesn't recognize, and then autocomplete the rest of the phrase, Atom *will not* erase what you've previously typed. I used to do this a bunch when I first started using Atom. The solution is simple: just type the part of the keyword that Atom recognizes before auto-completing the rest of it. So in the case of your first example image, you just have to start typing the phrase `media` and then press enter; no need to include the preceding `@` symbol. This ultimately means that you just have to type less to get your desired code, which I think is pretty sweet.

Comment: I am sorry but i don't find this an answer cause i am coming from Visual Studio where i am used to Intellisense replacing whatever i'v typed if i chose a suggestion which actually makes sense

Comment: Well I'm sorry but that's the best I can do. That _is_ the answer. Base Atom simply won't replace what you've already typed in if its not part of the keyword that it is looking for. If you'd rather have that functionality then I think your best bet would be to stick with VS

Comment: actually it does replace with any other word except for symbols so this seems like a bug rather than a limitation... Try typing dv or bt in an html file then auto-complete, you will see that it replaces whatever you've typed.

Comment: It's neither a bug nor a limitation. `@` is not part of the snippet prefix, therefore Atom doesn't consider it at all. You should just type `me`, not `@me`, and then when you press `tab` you will be left with `@media`. I can make a separate answer about how to override the snippet if you *really want* to type `@me`.

Comment: @HollandWilson Exactly